# Excel match 3 cells in range

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet that I need to find out if there are duplicate values for 3 of the cells within the range.  Basically I need to see if the Last Name, First Name and Address cells in one row match any other row exactly and then push it out to another range so I can use it as a report of duplicate values.  I've seen tons of tutorials on finding matches and using conditional formatting but not to match 3 cells, just one.  Is there a way to do this without VBA?

Comment: This is a perfect use for Advanced Filter.

Answer (score 0):

`=MATCH(1,(LastName_Value=LastName_SearchRange)*(FirstName_Value=FirstName_SearchRange)*(Address_Value=Address_SearchRange),0)`

It looks for a Match of 1 in the given conditions row by row. If a condition = TRUE it returns `1`, if FALSE `2`.
If one of the conditions is FALSE it will result in `0` (`*0=0`). If all 3 conditions are TRUE it returns a `1` (`1*1*1=1`). This formula returns the row number if found.